# How to identify error with Firebase Crashlytics on ios platform

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I got an error caught by Firebase Crashlytics. I was trying to understand the error, but the only thing that I was able to understand is in what function the error appears( `function getUrlTabelaAuxiliar()` ), but not the error that was generated inside thie method.

it show an error in the top of the site called:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT  0x0000000100528ec4
```

This is the log file that I get from Firebase Crashlytics

```
# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Application: br.gov.sp.prodesp.defesa.agropecuaria
# Platform: apple
# Version: 1.0.11 (2)
# Issue: 4bbffb5f6c732e4b23628144bf0aca64
# Session: 6962876022854805a64aeea415e3bf49_DNE_0_v2
# Date: Thu Mar 30 2023 17:01:38 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CDA                            0x8cec4 ResenhaEquideosMenuController.getUrlTabelaAuxiliar() + 494 (ResenhaEquideosMenuController.swift:494)
1  CDA                            0x89b64 ResenhaEquideosMenuController.verifyTimeAuxiliaryTable() + 139 (ResenhaEquideosMenuController.swift:139)
2  CDA                            0x8917c partial apply for closure #1 in ResenhaEquideosMenuController.viewDidLoad() + 4307210620 (<compiler-generated>:4307210620)
3  CDA                            0x264ac thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4306805932 (<compiler-generated>:4306805932)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x5b610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x5c184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0xe190 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1044
7  CoreFoundation                 0xa95e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0xa45d8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
9  CoreFoundation                 0xa3adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
10 GraphicsServices               0x3328 GSEventRunModal + 104
11 UIKitCore                      0xa03ae0 UIApplicationMain + 1936
12 CDA                            0x13bc24 main + 15 (AppDelegate.swift:15)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x1360 start + 4

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe758 start_wqthread + 190

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x25a7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xbbd4 _pthread_wqthread + 352
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe760 start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2aa0 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0xa9288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216
3  CoreFoundation                 0xa43a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444
4  CoreFoundation                 0xa3adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
5  Foundation                     0x77f4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6  Foundation                     0x76d4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7  UIKitCore                      0xa9c204 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152
8  Foundation                     0x1380a4 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xad8c _pthread_start + 156
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe76c thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x25a7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xbbd4 _pthread_wqthread + 352
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe760 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe758 start_wqthread + 190

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  CDA                            0x31a5f0 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 393 (FIRCLSProcess.c:393)
1  CDA                            0x31a9d0 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 424 (FIRCLSProcess.c:424)
2  CDA                            0x32714c FIRCLSHandler + 34 (FIRCLSHandler.m:34)
3  CDA                            0x327ad8 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 521 (FIRCLSMachException.c:521)
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xad8c _pthread_start + 156
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe76c thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x25a7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xbbd4 _pthread_wqthread + 352
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe760 start_wqthread + 8
```

How can I understand the error that Firebase Crashlytics caught?